# Can I access HTML DOM in other frame of other domain in UIWebView javascript injection?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, security, uiwebview, cross-domain

I'm injecting some JavaScript code to get internal DOM information of `UIWebView`. Currently, all of codes are irking well, but I met a big problem. The document in `IFRAME` of other domain. By cross-domain security policy, I can't access DOM of the IFRAME if the frame contains document which its address is different with current page. My `UIWebView` have to be able to process any sites on internet. Is there any way to evade this security policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `UIWebView`? No.

The only way around this would be to parse the HTML yourself (I'd suggest a library - [Element Parser](http://touchtank.wordpress.com/element-parser/) is pretty good). You'd obviously have to look for `IFRAME` tags and load that content recursively.

Comment: I have to handle even HTML elements created dynamically with JavaScript at runtime from client side. The job can become reimplementing web browser itself...

Comment: Anyway thanks for answering. I can stop digging on JavaScript injection. :)

Answer (score 0):

IFrames in the document can be found in the javascript variables `document.frames` this is an array containing all the iframes. Through this you can access the DOM of the iframe via javascript.

Using javascript you can callout to your UIWebViewDelegate by making a special request and process the iframes content.

Comment: Is this work on DOM in IFRAME contains document of different domain?

Comment: No, this is not possible due to security reasons. I am sorry, I read over the crossdomain part. If this would be possible through your app, people would find out and visit their website with your app and use this for cross domain scripting.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the reason of security :)